# Laptop screen only works when connected to external monitor

Tags: laptop

I have a strange problem where my laptop doesn't show a image on the screen when you turn it on, but it does if you use an external monitor and switch over to using the laptop screen and then unplug the monitor. Nothing is displayed if I don't do it this way, no BIOS screen or backlight or anything. Does anyone have an explanation for this weird behaviour? The screen isn't broken, and neither is the GPU it seems, since I can get an image just fine by switching to the laptop screen after Windows have started.

Comment: Have you tried hitting the key to switch between internal and external monitors a few times?

Comment: It might be helpful to specify the brand/model of your laptop, and the version of Windows you're using.  Also, tell us if this behavior began after you installed or configured something.

Comment: The laptop is an Acer Aspire 5930G running Windows 7. Switching between internal and external monitors solves the problem as long as the machine is on, but when it's shut down it's back to how it was. Restarting doesn't reset it. Nothing was changed or configured as far as I know, the problem appeared after I shut of the computer once.

Comment: have you checked the bios for primary display adapter? have you reset your bios to default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a broken monitor cable.